# Nokogiri replace strips content of HTML

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8, html-parsing, nokogiri

I would like to remove a tag from some HTML without stripping the remaining content of any markup. For example, I have a file, test.html:

```
<p class="P1"><span class="T2">Some text, goes to uppercase</span>
<p class="P4"><span class="T4"> </span><span class="T3">other text</span>
<span class="T5">italics</span><span class="T3">‘more text with UTF-8 ’</span>
</p></p>
```

I would like to get the following output:

```
SOME TEXT, GOES TO UPPERCASE
other text
<em>italics<em> ‘more text with UTF-8 ’
```

My code is:

```
f = File.open('raw/test.html',"r")
doc = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(f.read.encode('UTF-8'))
f.close

doc.css("span.T2").each do |span|
  span.replace span.content.upcase
end
doc.css("span.T5").each do |span|
  span.replace "<em>"+span.content+"</em>"
end
doc.css("span").each do |span|
  span.replace span.content
end
doc.css("p").each do |p|
  p.replace Nokogiri::XML::Text.new(p.inner_html, p.document)
end

f = File.open('processed/test.html',"w")
f.write(doc)
f.close
```

And the output I get is:

```
SOME TEXT, GOES TO UPPERCASE
&lt;p class="P4"&gt;
 other text
&lt;em&gt;italics &lt;/em&gt;&amp;#x2018;more text with UTF-8 &amp;#x2019;
&amp;#x2018;our common mother&amp;#x2019;
&lt;/p&gt;
```

Many thanks in advance.

## UPDATE

The solution was as follows:

```
coder = HTMLEntities.new 
f = File.open('raw/test.html',"r") 
doc = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(f.read.encode('UTF-8')) 
f.close 
doc.css("p").each do |p| 
  p.replace p.inner_html 
end 

doc.css("span.T2").each do |span| 
  span.replace span.content.upcase 
end 

doc.css("span.T5").each do |span| 
  span.replace "<em>"+span.content+"</em>" 
end 

doc.css("span").each do |span| 
  span.replace span.inner_html 
end 

f = File.open('processed/test.html',"w") 
f.write(coder.decode(doc)) 
f.close
```

Comment: Use `File.read` instead of `File.open` in the first File access. Use the block form of `File.open` when writing. It's safer, and more Ruby-idiomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `span.replace "<em>"+span.content+"</em>"` isn't correct. You need to tell Nokogiri to replace with HTML, not text. For instance:

```
span.inner_html = "<em>"+span.content+"</em>"
```

results in:

```
<span class="T5"><em>italics</em></span>
```

Comment: Thanks @the-Tin-Man. However, If I chabge `code`span.replace = "<em>+span.content+"/em"`code` to `code`span.inner_html = "<em>+span.content+"/em"`code` , it results with the following error (I am running Cygwin on Win7) `code` C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4.1-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri/xm
l/node.rb:743:in `[]': can't convert Symbol into Integer (TypeError) `code` Besides which, the desired result is `code`<em>italics</em>`code` not `code`<span class="T5"><em>italics</em></span>`code`

Comment: I eventually solved the problem as follows 
(install htmlentities gem): 

`code` 

coder = HTMLEntities.new  

f = File.open('raw/test.html',"r")
doc = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(f.read.encode('UTF-8'))
f.close

doc.css("p").each do |p|
  p.replace p.inner_html
end
doc.css("span.T2").each do |span|
  span.replace span.content.upcase
end
doc.css("span.T5").each do |span|
  span.replace "<em>"+span.content+"</em>"
end
doc.css("span").each do |span|
  span.replace span.inner_html
end

f = File.open('processed/test.html',"w")
f.write(coder.decode(doc))
f.close

`code`

Comment: If the above is a little unclear, I also posted this to [Google Groups](http://goo.gl/EMvBb)

Comment: Why not just re-edit your original question, and put the changes there? That way you can format it correctly and it will be available for everyone to see without having to go to another site. The fact you're loading htmlentities and post-processing the code looks like you're not replacing your HTML correctly still. I'll try to get time to look at a more complete solution, as you're jumping through hoops needlessly.